# maximize linear combination where parameters are non-negative and sum to 1

Tags: linear-programming

Here is the problem:

$$L = \sum_{i\in [1,n]} a_i x_i \\
s.t. \sum_{i\in [1,n]} x_i = 1, \text{and } x_i >= 0
$$

I think this is a linear programming problem, and I tried to solve it by Lagrange multiplier but no idea at all.

However, I know that the solution is
$$x = [0,...,x_k=1,0,0,0], \text{where } k = \text{argmax}_i(a_i)$$
, but how to solve it formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x' = (x_1', \ldots, x_n')$ be the optimal solution (it exists since this is a classical linear programming problem with nonempty domain) and $a_k$ is the max coefficient in $L$. We have

$$
L(x') = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ix_i' \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_kx_i' = a_k\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i' = a_k = L(x^*),
$$
where $x^* = (0, \ldots, 0, x_k = 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$.